# Exit from less by pressing ESC key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, less

Can I setup `less` program to exit from it by pressing `ESC` key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To bind <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to `quit` with `lesskey`, do the following:

1. Create a `~/.lesskey` file with the line:

```
\e\e quit
```

2. Run `lesskey`. This will create a binary `~/.less` file used by `less`.
3. Use `less` as usual. <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will do a `quit`.

If you no longer want your bindings, you can remove the `~/.less` file.

---

For more details, see `man lesskey` or `lesskey.nro` in the `less` package source.
[Debian -- Details of source package less in wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/less)

```
SYNOPSIS
       lesskey [-o output] [--] [input]

The input file is a text file which describes the key bindings.
If the input file is "-", standard input is read.
If no input file is specified, a standard filename is used
as the name of the input file, which depends on the system being used:
On Unix systems, $HOME/.lesskey is used;
on MS-DOS systems, $HOME/_lesskey is used;
and on OS/2 systems $HOME/lesskey.ini is used,
or $INIT/lesskey.ini if $HOME is undefined.
```

Comment: Nice one! This works well!

Comment: I had just found this while poking around in the source only to realize this answer was here already. I really appreciate that the consideration the developers have shown for the user by including `lesskey`.

Answer (score 7):

Not really.

`less` has many functions bound to <kbd>ESC</kbd> + something else. See the manpage: <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, many others. You wouldn't be able to type any of those is `less` exited upon receiving just <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Concievably, you could rebind all those functions to other keystrokes or live with being unable to type them, and rebind <kbd>ESC</kbd> to quitting, but it still wouldn't be a good idea.

It's not a good choice of key to use. In VT100 (the terminal emulation used basically everywhere these days) all terminal control sequences begin with the ASCII `ESC` character. This means that every time you press something like an arrow key, your terminal sends `ESC` followed by other stuff. When you press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, your terminal also sends `ESC`, but it's not followed by anything. How can software tell the difference after having received an ASCII `ESC` character? It is forced to wait a some time to see if anything follows the `ESC`. So things bound to <kbd>ESC</kbd> alone always incur a delay, a time lag before the software can respond.

Comment: It a really good explanation. As you said, many functions of less bound to `esc`+something else. It would be cool to setup quit from less by pressing `Esc`+`Esc`. Is it possible?

Comment: Terminal control sequences starting with `ESC` are sent **to** the terminal, not received from it. Pressing the Escape key adds keycode 27 to the input stream immediately... You can test this yourself with the code at http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html

Comment: @ArturEshenbrener You can bind to ESC+ESC with `\e\e`. See the lesskey(1) man page.

Comment: @StephenKitt terminal control sequences starting with `ESC` are both sent **to** the terminal and received **from** the terminal. An example of **from** the terminal is an arrow key. An example of **to** the terminal is an instruction to move the cursor.

Comment: Oops, you're right about arrow keys, sorry. Handling Escape doesn't necessarily involve much of a delay though (see how Emacs handles Esc-X vs. arrows for example).

Comment: Double `esc` does the job. Thank you. Think that it could be added to your answer.

Comment: @ArturEshenbrener You know what? I looked into `lesskey` before I wrote my answer and I couldn't figure out how to use it. I just kept on getting `Cannot use lesskey file ".lesskey"`. If you got it working and got it to bind ESC+ESC then I encourage you to add your own self-answer with the method or edit the information into mine; your choice.

Comment: @Celada See my answer on how to use `lesskey`.